# Reputation for useful flag

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags, reputation

Since flags tend to improve this website quality and tend to reduce 'noise' in the question thread: would it be a good idea to give a small reputation amount for an helpful flags?

Comment: No, flagging is working fine as it is. We don't need more ways for people to go hunting for things to flag and add to the moderator workload, just because some rep is on the line.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

We already provide an incentive to give us helpful flags with the Deputy and Marshal badges. Plenty of people flagged happily before those badges came into existence, and many more do now that they are around.

Frankly, I want people to be flagging things because they're motivated to keep the site clean, not because of some arbitrary points. We only need flags for the items where moderators really do need to step in (or for low-rep users who can't yet vote to close posts).

We already have some trouble with people who farm helpful flags to game the existing badges, and if reputation was involved that would get much worse. Not to mention the fact that we'd get called out for every single declined flag on Meta because they didn't get reputation for them. I would not look forward to that.

Comment: How can you have trouble with helpful flags ???

Comment: Maybe ‘farming helpful flags’ means viewing existing flags, duplicating them, and hoping that the other person was correct so that your flag will be “helpful”.

Comment: @CarlG How is that a problem? Doesn't that just increase the visibility of an existing flagged post in the review queue? If the flag is incorrect, the user messed up for themselves. If it's useful, well, it increased the likelihood that off-topic content was handled.