# Allow "View Deleted Posts" privilege (and other 10k tools) based on Helpful Flagging?

Tags: feature-request, flags, 10k-tools

As background, I think most people know that there's a smaller sub-community of users here who do a *lot* of the flagging of posts suspected to be generated by AI/LLM (e.g., ChatGPT).  Flags are welcome from anyone, of course, but certain users have gone above-and-beyond.

What I realized today when chatting with one of them is that at least three of these users, while having literally thousands of helpful flags (not all AI, of course), don't have the 10k Rep needed to view deleted posts, which is (for reasons I won't go into in detail, but may be somewhat obvious) really quite useful when flagging AI-posts.  It's not *critical*, of course, but it sure does make things easier from time to time.  An example came up today where the user who was looking into a post would have saved a bit of time if they could have seen the other, already deleted answer on the same question.

Users contribute to SO in different ways -- Those with quality questions and answers receive, of course, Rep and the eventual privileges that go with along with it.

These users with thousands of helpful *post* flags, IMHO, contribute just as much (and even more than *some* 10k users based on time invested in the site).  More importantly, their direct contribution to the site's curation-and-moderation seems like a *better* metric for accessing the "10k tools" than Rep.

I know that, with the current Staff cuts, it's going to be difficult to get this *implemented*, but what does the Community think about also allowing access to the "10k Tools" (a.k.a. "Moderator Tools") for users with, say, 1.5k or 2k helpful post flags (not including comment flags, etc.)?

And as @Jesse mentions in the comments, perhaps other tools like access to review queues, close/reopen votes, and others would be well-utilized by this same set of Reviewers/Flaggers as well.

Comment: Related, but with a different end-goal in mind - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254850/reputation-for-useful-flag

Comment: Alas, I only have about 1.2k helpful post flags (many of which are NAA flags). I would have about 1.4k including spam flags. (And trying to do more would likely just burn me out.) I wonder what numbers everyone else in AI Domination has, since the number in the public profile includes all helpful flags, a lot of which might be comment flags.

Comment: Related: [Allow moderators to see deleted posts network wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294951/323179). Admittedly, this would be more useful for reasons other than handling AI (especially since most active users in AI Domination are not mods anywhere).

Comment: I think the proposal contains that anyway, but please do not enable to 10k tools only based on flags but also when you reach 10k (like now). I would miss the tools very much and have only 650 flags. On the other hand, I have more than 18k reviews, so maybe the number of reviews done could also enable the 10k tools?

Comment: @BDL Agreed - Edited to make that clear.

Comment: This sort of thing would be a good first step towards making a privilege system that actually makes sense. Tying everything to reputation [fundamentally must fail](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387356). Codidact has taken a few more steps in the right direction, but their system is still quite primitive.

Comment: Regarding viewing deleted stuff, IMO anyone who can do reviews should be able to do that. But the content shouldn't be visible by default, I don't want my normal day-to-day usage of the site be polluted by deleted content. But when I would follow a link to a deleted question from meta for example, I should be able to see it. And perhaps a checkbox which allows you to see deleted answers under a question.

Comment: @Gimby Deleted content has red overlay and deleted answers are listed at the end. It is not interfering with day to day usage in any way.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar fair enough. Rephrase: I don't want to be distracted by deleted content in my normal day to day usage. Deleted content really should only be visible when you have an interest in seeing it.

Comment: @Gimby Then you should try to stay below 10K ;) I know people are different, so what is fine for me might not be fine for others, but seriously I have never though "Why am I seeing this" comparing to frustration when you cannot see something on some other site, you know it exists. When the post literally makes poof under your nose and it is gone. I wouldn't want to have to click around in order to see deleted answers. right now I just need to scroll a bit more.

Comment: I think it also makes sense to add the "Low quality answers" review queue, and potentially even the ability to cast close/re-open votes to this list of privileges for active and helpful flaggers. They are, after all, the users who see low quality questions/answers the most, and the ones that are the most willing to do these types of tasks.

Comment: @Jesse Great point - Added as part of the question.  Thanks!

Comment: I'd be interested in experimenting with giving anyone with flagging privileges access to New Answers to Old Questions and see how they do with correctly flagging non-answers. I think it's not difficult once you get the hang of it.